# Javascript getCookie functions

Tags: javascript, cookies

I found two functions to get cookie data with Javascript, one on [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp) and one on [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)
I would like to know which one I should use?

For example I believe I read somewhere that there was a problem with some browsers splitting the `;` semicolon?

w3schools:

```
function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) c_end = document.cookie.length;
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

quirksmode:

```
function readCokie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: They both go looking for `;` characters to split up cookies, which as far as I know is always correct.

Comment: The `getCookie` function is wrong, think at what happens if you get a cookies named `ART=` and you have a cookies named `SMART=`

Comment: w3schools has since changed their getCookie function (see http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp), probably works better now.

Comment: They are using the same function now - just with different names and whitespaces.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The function from W3CSchool is wrong. It fails if there are multiple cookies that have the same suffix like:

```
ffoo=bar; foo=baz
```

When you search for `foo` it will return the value of *ffoo* instead of *foo*.

Now here is what I would do: First of all, you need get to know the syntax of how cookies are transported. Netscape’s original specification (there are only copies available like [this one at haxx.se](http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html)) uses semicolons to separate multiple cookies while each name/value pair has the following syntax:

> *NAME*`=`*VALUE*
> This string is a sequence of characters excluding semi-colon, comma and white space. If there is a need to place such data in the name or value, some encoding method such as URL style `%XX` encoding is recommended, though no encoding is defined or required.

So splitting `document.cookie` string at semi-colons or commas is a viable option.

Besides that, [RFC 2109](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109) does also specify that cookies are separated by either semi-colons or commas:

> ```
> cookie          =       "Cookie:" cookie-version
>                         1*((";" | ",") cookie-value)
> cookie-value    =       NAME "=" VALUE [";" path] [";" domain]
> cookie-version  =       "$Version" "=" value
> NAME            =       attr
> VALUE           =       value
> path            =       "$Path" "=" value
> domain          =       "$Domain" "=" value
> ```

Although both are allowed, commas are preferred as they are the default separator of list items in HTTP.

> Note: For backward compatibility, the separator in the Cookie header
> is semi-colon (`;`) everywhere.  A server should also accept comma (`,`)
> as the separator between cookie-values for future compatibility.

Furthermore, the name/value pair has some further restrictions as the *VALUE* can also be a quoted string as specified in [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616):

> ```
> attr        =     token
> value       =     token | quoted-string
> ```

So these two cookie versions need to be treated separately:

```
if (typeof String.prototype.trimLeft !== "function") {
    String.prototype.trimLeft = function() {
        return this.replace(/^\s+/, "");
    };
}
if (typeof String.prototype.trimRight !== "function") {
    String.prototype.trimRight = function() {
        return this.replace(/\s+$/, "");
    };
}
if (typeof Array.prototype.map !== "function") {
    Array.prototype.map = function(callback, thisArg) {
        for (var i=0, n=this.length, a=[]; i<n; i++) {
            if (i in this) a[i] = callback.call(thisArg, this[i]);
        }
        return a;
    };
}
function getCookies() {
    var c = document.cookie, v = 0, cookies = {};
    if (document.cookie.match(/^\s*\$Version=(?:"1"|1);\s*(.*)/)) {
        c = RegExp.$1;
        v = 1;
    }
    if (v === 0) {
        c.split(/[,;]/).map(function(cookie) {
            var parts = cookie.split(/=/, 2),
                name = decodeURIComponent(parts[0].trimLeft()),
                value = parts.length > 1 ? decodeURIComponent(parts[1].trimRight()) : null;
            cookies[name] = value;
        });
    } else {
        c.match(/(?:^|\s+)([!#$%&'*+\-.0-9A-Z^`a-z|~]+)=([!#$%&'*+\-.0-9A-Z^`a-z|~]*|"(?:[\x20-\x7E\x80\xFF]|\\[\x00-\x7F])*")(?=\s*[,;]|$)/g).map(function($0, $1) {
            var name = $0,
                value = $1.charAt(0) === '"'
                          ? $1.substr(1, -1).replace(/\\(.)/g, "$1")
                          : $1;
            cookies[name] = value;
        });
    }
    return cookies;
}
function getCookie(name) {
    return getCookies()[name];
}
```

Comment: I'd move `trimRight` and `trimLeft` out of the `getCookie` function: you only need to set them once.

Comment: what's that part of the code where you check the $Version? It's the 1st time I see it in getCookie like functions. Is it still useful?

Comment: @Marco Demaio: The `$Version=1` attribute is part of the RFC specifications to identify the cookies of those specifications and might get important when browsers start to implement them (although I’m not sure how the `document.cookie` value will reflect that).

Comment: Internet Explorer 8 doesn't support the javascript array map function, (added it in the code above as IE8 is unfortunately still around) code taken from http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/884/

Comment: getCookie(name) should use hasOwnProperty to avoid returning something in Object.prototype as a cookie

Comment: This answer is a prime example of overengineering. Why include all of that code, when the problem can easily be solved by creating a cookie name that is very likely to be unique. eg. NAMESPACE_KEY

Comment: This answer appears to choke on anything with '=' as part of the cookie's value. Compare the answer's `getCookies()` function with `document.cookie.split('; ')`

Comment: "A server should also accept comma (,) as the separator between cookie-values for future compatibility." How is this possible if "expires" values can contain commas?

Comment: This code didn't work for double-quoted cookie values containing equal signs.  The js-cookie library proposed in another answer was able to handle that case.

Comment: I think this answer is extremly outdated. [RFC 6265](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265) specifies semicolons as the separator, not commas.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, the W3Schools solution is **incorrect**.

For those that would like it, here is a **simpler solution** that works. It just prepends a space so the single call to indexOf() only returns the correct cookie.

```
function getCookie(c_name) {
    var c_value = " " + document.cookie;
    var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
    if (c_start == -1) {
        c_value = null;
    }
    else {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
        var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
        if (c_end == -1) {
            c_end = c_value.length;
        }
        c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
    }
    return c_value;
}
```

Comment: Nowadays  decodeURIComponent  should be preferred over unescape. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) for details.

Answer (score 6):

This, from w3schools, is ***incorrect*** in that it may lead to getting the wrong cookie:

```
c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
```

If you go looking for a cookie named `foo` (which we'll suppose is an existing cookie) then somewhere in `document.cookie` will be the string `foo=bar`.

However, there's no guarantee there won't ***also*** be the string `xfoo=something`. Notice that this still contains the substring `foo=` so the w3schools code will find it. And if the `xfoo` cookie happens to be listed first, you'll get back the `something` value (incorrectly!) instead of the expected `bar`.

Given the choice between two pieces of code, never go with the one that's fundamentally broken.

Answer (score 2):

All of the code shown above is BROKEN. The two common problems are (1) the getcookie function may return the wrong value if one cookie name is a proper suffix of another cookie name; and (2) the setcookie function does not protect the cookie value, which means that if the cookie value includes (for example) a ";" then all the cookies are corrupted and cannot be parsed.

TL;DR Use this well-written library instead:
https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Comment: Tried the accepted answer for double-quoted cookie values containing equal signs, and it didn't work, but js-cookie did the job.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version, it covers the edge case of quoted values.

```js
function getCookies() {
  const REGEXP = /([\w\.]+)\s*=\s*(?:"((?:\\"|[^"])*)"|(.*?))\s*(?:[;,]|$)/g;
  let cookies = {};
  let match;
  while( (match = REGEXP.exec(document.cookie)) !== null ) {
    let value = match[2] || match[3];
    cookies[match[1]] = decodeURIComponent(value);
  }
  return cookies;
}
```