# get all cookies of my site

Tags: php, javascript

how can i get all the cookies set by my site using js. I dont want to do say     **Cookie("username")** but loop through all the cookies and get the key=value pairs of my site

Comment: You've tagged this PHP and JavaScript. Which language are you using? Neither of them have a built in function called `getCookie`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(/;/);
for (var i = 0, len = cookies.length; i < len; i++) {
   var cookie = cookies[i].split(/=/);
   alert("key: " + cookie[0] + ", value: " + cookie[1]);
}
```

Comment: [document.cookie()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie) is as close as you can get but it doesn't retrieve all the cookies from the site—it merely retrieves cookies from current *document*.

Comment: That is not true. "Documents" don't have cookies. Cookies are stored per domain, or they can be assigned to a path within that domain, but that has nothing to do with the JavaScript/DOM concept of documents.

Comment: Yet the `cookie` method belongs to the `document` object? I'm not saying your answer is wrong, I'm just stating that the original question ("get all the cookies set by my site") cannot be answered. Running your snippet from e.g. `/` will not list cookies set for `/another-path` (even though the browser cookie manager shows they exist). It's very easy [to test locally](http://pastebin.com/k5UNYhBe).

Comment: The `cookie` *property* isn't very well designed. But since there is no `domain` object, the `document` makes more sense than the `window` object, which would be the only other choice. I think the path can be ignored in this case.

Comment: I've posted test code that verifies my assertion (that `document.cookie` takes path into account). Can you please post test code that verifies yours?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `getCookie` from [my answer to *Javascript getCookie functions*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003823/javascript-getcookie-functions/4004010#4004010) and split it into a `getCookies` and `getCookie` function where the `getCookies` function simply returns `cookies` instead of `cookies[name]`. And for the `getCookie` function just take the return value of `getCookies` and use `[name]` on it.

---

**Update**    Ok, I simply added the functions according to the description above. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please read about reading/writing cookies in JavaScript.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

You are probably looking for a solution like this: [Get all cookies with Javascript](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-get-all-cookies/)

The following function loads all the cookie items into an associative array with the cookie name as the index and the cookie value as the value:

```
function get_cookies_array() {

    var cookies = { };

    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var split = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            var name_value = split[i].split("=");
            name_value[0] = name_value[0].replace(/^ /, '');
            cookies[decodeURIComponent(name_value[0])] = decodeURIComponent(name_value[1]);
        }
    }

    return cookies;

}
```

After that, you can get the cookies and write them out into the document like this:

```
var cookies = get_cookies_array();
for(var name in cookies) {
  document.write( name + " : " + cookies[name] + "<br />" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function checkCookie()
{
var username=getCookie("username");
if (username!=null && username!="")
  {
  alert("Welcome again " + username);
  }
else 
  {
  username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
  if (username!=null && username!="")
    {
    setCookie("username",username,365);
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkCookie()">
</body>
</html>
```

copy pasted from : http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp