# jquery keep div visible-select option even when you refresh a page

Tags: html, jquery, radio-button, show-hide, page-refresh

I searched this site and around the net, but I have not found anything that I would solve my problem.

I have 4 radio, that if you select show / hide the div containing 4 registration forms . This works perfectly .

I have 2 select populated by containing and countries. This works perfectly .

**I have 2 problems :**

1 ) My problem is that if you update the page or the user clicks the submit button the div disappears , that is, the page returns to its initial state .

I would like the div shown to remain visible , even when you refresh the page or if there are errors in the validation of the module.

2) The second problem is always when you reload the page 2 select that contain the " continents" and countries , they return to the initial state , I do not stay on the choice made by the user.

I would like the choice of the continent and the country made ​​by the user remains selected even when you refresh the page

I'm learning jquery recently .

I hope someone give me a hand.

I hope to be as clear as possible .

Sorry for the bad English.

**This is the html code:**

```
<select id="continent" onchange="countryChange(this);" class="elementiForm">
      <option value="empty">Seleziona un Continente</option>
      <option value="Europa">Europa</option>    
      <option value="Nord America">Nord America</option>
      <option value="Sud America">South America</option>
      <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
      <option value="Oceania">Oceania</option>
      <option value="Africa">Africa</option>        
</select>

<label for="country" class="labelForm">Seleziona uno Stato</label>
      <select id="country" class="elementiForm">
      <option value="0" >Seleziona uno Stato</option>
</select>

<!-- below the div that contain the headlights form -->
<div id="contatti_RS" class="red box">
    societa form here ...
</div>

<div id="privato" class="green box">
    privato form here ...
</div>

<div id="ditta_professionista" class="blue box">
    ditta_professionista form here ...
</div>

<div id="associazione" class="black box">
    associazione form here ...
</div>
```

**this is my jquery to show / hide divs**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

      $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="societa"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".red").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="privato"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".green").show();
            }
             if($(this).attr("value")=="ditta_professionista"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".blue").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="associazione"){
                $(".box").hide();
                $(".black").show();
            }



        });
```

**this is my jquery that controls whether the radio is selected on page refresh**

```
$(function()
{
    $('input[type=radio]').each(function()
    {
        var state = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('radio_'  + this.id) );

        if (state) this.checked = state.checked;
        });
});

$(window).bind('unload', function()
{
    $('input[type=radio]').each(function()
    {
        localStorage.setItem(
            'radio_' + this.id, JSON.stringify({checked: this.checked})
        );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible use AJAX (jQuery get or post)

If using AJAX is not possible, you can remember your settings in cookie. E.g. you can set

```
exp = Date.now();
exp += 84600000; //validity one day
document.cookie = "mycookie=" + some_value + "expires=" +
    (new Date(d)).toGMTString();
```

After reload you then parse the cookie ([Read a javascript cookie by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142337/read-a-javascript-cookie-by-name)) and set the page state accordingly.

Comment: I know little about Ajax, I'm starting to learn jquery for a short time, however, so I can keep the div is visible is the choice of the continent and the country, from the user?

Comment: I am working with codeigniter, maybe I can use helper set_cookie ()?

Comment: I don't know codeigniter, but if it sets cookie then use it ... ;-)

Comment: What I wanted to say with Ajax - if you will download just data that are used, you don't have to reload page. So what is shown stays shown and you have better control over the DOM manipulations. But since it requires also changing the server side, you probably would start with cookies only.