# Ruby Sinatra Sessions in a JSX file?

Tags: ruby, reactjs, sinatra

I'm a newbie to integrating react + ruby and was wondering if there is a way to access my sessions contents that I stored?

For example, in my `app.rb`, I'm storing `sessions[:return_url]=blah.com`. I'm currently using reactjs for my UI and want to access this return_url upon a button click. Is there a way to access it?

I've tried doing `<%= return_url = sesssions[:return_url] %>` but this doesn't work because I'm in a .jsx file and it can't interpret this haha (it was worth a shot)

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: you can't read the rails session from the client as per my understanding, but you might be able to do it through Ajax request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read session related non-sensitive data on the client side, you can set a cookie from the server and read it using javascript on the client side.

You can set `cookies` with Sinatra as detailed here: http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/cookies

And you can read cookies with Javascript as detailed here: [Read a javascript cookie by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142337/read-a-javascript-cookie-by-name)

An alternative would be to render javascript on the server-side and store the value in a javascript variable. I believe you already tried this:

```
<%= return_url = sesssions[:return_url] %>`
```

But that is only setting a Ruby local variable, which is lost on the client side, maybe you want set that return_url as the `href` of the button you want to have clicked?

But, if you needed the variable inside a javascript click handler, just render a javascript variable in your ERB view:

```
var returnUrl = "<%= sessions[:return_url] %>";
```

With the above you should be access to the javascript variable `returnUrl` in a button click handler provided it's in the same or higher lexical scope.