# JSON encoded array converted to string when saved as cookie

Tags: javascript, json, cookies

I have a simple array that I'm trying to JSON encode and set as a cookie. I am using the json2.js script to encode to JSON. I am using the following code to set the cookie:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var ids = ['1', '2'];
    JSON.stringify(ids);
    setCookie(cookieName, ids, 1);
});

function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
```

After converting the array to JSON, and logging it in console, I get:

```
["1", "2"]
```

which is what I would expect. I then read out the cookie with the following function

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I read out the cookie and log it in the console, I get:

```
1,2
```

suggesting that its a string and no longer a JSON encoded object. I would like to be able to set a cookie an a JSON encoded object, read it out and parse the JSON object, and finally perform operations on the data. My question is thus, how do you send a JSON encoded object to the cookie in such a way that I can parse it as JSON when I read it out?

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
JSON.stringify(ids);
setCookie(cookieName, ids, 1);
```

To this:

```
var str = JSON.stringify(ids);
setCookie(cookieName, str, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's why I ask these questions. After working on this for a while, I cannot see little issues like this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see you actually using the result of the JSON stringification:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var ids = ['1', '2'];
    setCookie(cookieName, JSON.stringify(ids), 1);
});
```

Try this instead

Comment: +1 Thank you so much! Pretty obvious, eh? It's amazing I did not catch that.

Answer (score 2):

Don’t use these cookie functions, they are flawed. `setCookie` fails to encode the name and value properly and `getCookie` fails for cookies with a common suffix (see [my answer to *Javascript getCookie functions*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003823/javascript-getcookie-functions/4004010#4004010)).

For `setCookie` I would use this:

```
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days > 0) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(name)+"="+encodeURIComponent(value)+expires+"; path=/";
}
```

Comment: I implemented this function; however, since doing so, when I attempt to delete a cookie using `setCookie(name,"",-1);` it deletes only the value of the cookie, not the cookie entirely. Prior to changing it to your function, it would work as expected. Any thoughts? Thanks again!

Comment: I solved this by setting `var expires = "; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT";`