# How to load Cookie on my page

Tags: javascript, cookies

Is it possible to write a page that open my site and show my cookie for the site? For example, open mysite.com and alert me my cookie at mysite.com.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just want to know , how it is possible ...

Comment: Yes its possible, Here is an example its easy to follow check out http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: Check this article [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003823/javascript-getcookie-functions/4004010#4004010)

Comment: I found this blog article it might help you : http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: Thanks @questborn , ur article is hard for me .  may u give me a simple code ?

Comment: Check this article [link](http://www.blazonry.com/javascript/cookies_save.php). It's pretty simple.

Comment: Thanks all , lastly i understand that its NotPOSSIBLE .

Answer (score 0):

`document.cookie` in JavaScript contains all the cookies of the current document. So, you can easily alert that, or write it somewhere in your page. So, a simple answer could be:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var cookiesString = document.cookie;
    document.write("<div>" + cookieString + "</div>");
};
```

Comment: yes it show me the Cookie , but i want open mysite.com and show the cookie of this page .

Comment: If you mean that from a.com you want to show cookies of b.com, then I gotta tell you that it's impossible. But if you want to show the cookies which are set for your website, then all those cookies which are related to the current path are delivered to you via `document.cookie` object by browser. :)

Comment: no there is no 2 site , a page for e.x : saeed.html and when u open it show us our cookie of mysite.com

Comment: Then I don't understand what you mean. I think you should completely describe your problem, including the absolute URLs. For example, `http://site1.com/page1.html` and `http://site2.com/cookie.html` and so on. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ar = document.cookie.replace(/;/g,"<br/>");
document.body.innerHTML += "<div style='background:white;position:fixed;top:0;'>"+unescape(ar)+"</div>";
```

you can add a "javascript:" and use it as a bookmark;
add a new bookmark and set the location to :

```
javascript:var ar = document.cookie.replace(/;/g,"<br/>");document.body.innerHTML += "<div style='background:white;position:fixed;top:0;'>"+unescape(ar)+"</div>";
```