# JavaScript set and get cookies?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have a function that saves cookies

```
    cookievalue= escape(document.passwordCheck.oldPassword.value) + ";";
    document.cookie="oldCookie=" + cookievalue
    cookievalue= escape(document.passwordCheck.oldPassword.value) + ";";
    document.cookie="newCookie=" + cookievalue
```

How do I retrieve the data for oldCookie and newCookie?

Comment: Have you ever tried to search for solution?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003823/javascript-getcookie-functions

Comment: You should not store passwords in cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp:

```
function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++) {
        x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        if (x==c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The function of W3CSchool is wrong. It fails if there are multiple cookies that have the same suffix like:

```
ffoo=bar; foo=baz
```

When you search for `foo` it will return the value of *ffoo* instead of *foo*.

Now here is what I would do: First of all, you need get to know the syntax of how cookies are transported. Netscape’s original specification (there are only copies available like [this one at haxx.se](http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html)) uses semicolons to separate multiple cookies while each name/value pair has the following syntax:

> *NAME*`=`*VALUE*
> This string is a sequence of characters excluding semi-colon, comma and white space. If there is a need to place such data in the name or value, some encoding method such as URL style `%XX` encoding is recommended, though no encoding is defined or required.

So splitting `document.cookie` string at semi-colons or commas is a viable option.

Besides that, [RFC 2109](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109) does also specify that cookies are separated by either semi-colons or commas:

> ```
> cookie          =       "Cookie:" cookie-version
>                         1*((";" | ",") cookie-value)
> cookie-value    =       NAME "=" VALUE [";" path] [";" domain]
> cookie-version  =       "$Version" "=" value
> NAME            =       attr
> VALUE           =       value
> path            =       "$Path" "=" value
> domain          =       "$Domain" "=" value
> ```

Although both are allowed, commas are preferred as they are the default separator of list items in HTTP.

> Note: For backward compatibility, the separator in the Cookie header
> is semi-colon (`;`) everywhere.  A server should also accept comma (`,`)
> as the separator between cookie-values for future compatibility.

Furthermore, the name/value pair has some further restrictions as the *VALUE* can also be a quoted string as specified in [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616):

> ```
> attr        =     token
> value       =     token | quoted-string
> ```

So these two cookie versions need to be treated separately:

```
if (typeof String.prototype.trimLeft !== "function") {
    String.prototype.trimLeft = function() {
        return this.replace(/^\s+/, "");
    };
}
if (typeof String.prototype.trimRight !== "function") {
    String.prototype.trimRight = function() {
        return this.replace(/\s+$/, "");
    };
}
if (typeof Array.prototype.map !== "function") {
    Array.prototype.map = function(callback, thisArg) {
        for (var i=0, n=this.length, a=[]; i<n; i++) {
            if (i in this) a[i] = callback.call(thisArg, this[i]);
        }
        return a;
    };
}
function getCookies() {
    var c = document.cookie, v = 0, cookies = {};
    if (document.cookie.match(/^\s*\$Version=(?:"1"|1);\s*(.*)/)) {
        c = RegExp.$1;
        v = 1;
    }
    if (v === 0) {
        c.split(/[,;]/).map(function(cookie) {
            var parts = cookie.split(/=/, 2),
                name = decodeURIComponent(parts[0].trimLeft()),
                value = parts.length > 1 ? decodeURIComponent(parts[1].trimRight()) : null;
            cookies[name] = value;
        });
    } else {
        c.match(/(?:^|\s+)([!#$%&'*+\-.0-9A-Z^`a-z|~]+)=([!#$%&'*+\-.0-9A-Z^`a-z|~]*|"(?:[\x20-\x7E\x80\xFF]|\\[\x00-\x7F])*")(?=\s*[,;]|$)/g).map(function($0, $1) {
            var name = $0,
                value = $1.charAt(0) === '"'
                          ? $1.substr(1, -1).replace(/\\(.)/g, "$1")
                          : $1;
            cookies[name] = value;
        });
    }
    return cookies;
}
function getCookie(name) {
    return getCookies()[name];
}
```

***Sourced from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4004010***

Comment: Sourced or not, you shouldn't rip other answers. If a question is a duplicate, link to the existing question in a comment.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Sure... :) Will follow from next! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a cookie library or other function to get value.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Development/Cookiesetdeletegetvalueandcreate.htm

```
function getCookieVal (offset) {
  var endstr = document.cookie.indexOf (";", offset);
  if (endstr == -1) { endstr = document.cookie.length; }
  return unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, endstr));
}

function getCookie (name) {
  var arg = name + "=";
  var alen = arg.length;
  var clen = document.cookie.length;
  var i = 0;
  while (i < clen) {
    var j = i + alen;
    if (document.cookie.substring(i, j) == arg) {
      return getCookieVal (j);
      }
    i = document.cookie.indexOf(" ", i) + 1;
    if (i == 0) break; 
    }
     return null;
  }
```

Comment: You shouldn't start a non-constructor function name with a capital letter