# Small Javascript code that will just Read a Cookie (give it's value)?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, cookies

To create a cookie in javascript I use

```
document.cookie = "cookieName=cookieValue;expires=myDate;path=/"
```

To read a cookie: I read many articles in the web including w3schools, but they give complicated codes with `for(;;){}` method and `split`. I don't need such codes. I just need a small javascript code.

If anyone can, please give me a code that will display an alert with the value of `'cookieName'` cookie?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript getCookie functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003823/javascript-getcookie-functions)

Comment: It might, but I am asking for something easier and not complicated

Comment: If you want something that works reliably, then this is probably as easy as it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be the easiest way I can give you.

Call the function it returns cooke value:

```
      /**     
    * Returns cookie.
    * @param {String} sName Main cookie name.
    * @param {String} SubName Sub cookie name.
    * @return {String} Cookie.     
    */


GetCookie: function (sName, SubName) {
        var aCookie = document.cookie.split("; "); // cookies are separated by semicolons
        var CookieVal = null;
        var bHasKeys;
        for (var i = 0; i < aCookie.length; i++) {
            var aCrumb = aCookie[i].split("=");
            bHasKeys = aCrumb.length > 2 ? 1 : 0;
            if (sName == aCrumb[0]) {
                var TempVal = aCookie[i];
                TempVal = TempVal.substring(TempVal.indexOf(sName) + sName.length + 1, TempVal.length);
                if (SubName) {
                    TempArr = TempVal.split("&"); // subcookie seperated by &
                    for (var j = 0; j < TempArr.length; j++) {
                        if (TempArr[j].split("=")[0] == SubName) {
                            CookieVal = TempArr[j].split("=")[1];
                            //while loop is added since /+/g syantax does not work here
                            while (CookieVal.indexOf("+") != -1) CookieVal = CookieVal.replace('+', ' ');
                            CookieVal = unescape(CookieVal);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (bHasKeys) CookieVal = TempVal;
                    else {
                        CookieVal = aCrumb[1];
                        //while loop is added since /+/g syantax does not work here
                        while (CookieVal.indexOf("+") != -1) CookieVal = CookieVal.replace('+', ' ');
                        CookieVal = unescape(CookieVal);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return CookieVal == null ? '' : CookieVal;
    }
```

Comment: why it is needed the for(){}, and how this code will give me the alert

Comment: Amden its a method which u can call wherever you need and give the return type as alert thats it !
Usually cookies will be maintained in nested objects ex:
In my browser cookies :
G=SS=bengaluru%2Dvisitmachine%2D29&MT=&F=0&M=1&G=0&U=1&N=0&R=32&D=1&B=0&P=0&V=0&H=0&S=0&L=English; 


In your code ::

alert('G','U');

gives alert 1