# Javascript form validation based on PHP session variables

Tags: php, javascript, validation

I have a login area of my site, and on login I set a session variable `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true`.

Now I also have lots of forms and things where users can input comments. Obviously in my PHP validation I check the user is logged in simply using the session variable, but I want javascript validation too because I can make the user experience slicker that way.

```
$("body").on("click", ".submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (user == logged in){
        ...AJAX call to php file....
    }
})
```

So how do people generally do the bit where I check the user is logged in using javascript? 
ie
 `if user == logged in`

Comment: First I will mention that you should validate on the backend too. But, to answer the question, you can inject php variables into js... so if you have `$loggedIn = true`, you can do this is js: `if (<?php echo $loggedIn ?>)`

Comment: Is this "the" way people do it? It does get the job done, but I somehow don't really like the mix of javascript and php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can of course check user permissions by AJAX (with JSON for example), but this will provide some additional latency.
- You can just write a value to global JS scope like this:

  `if ( userIsLogged() ) {
  echo "<script>document.mysite.userlogged = true;</script>";
  }`

  then you can check document.mysite.userlogged variable.
- You can also set a cookie in PHP, wich can be obtained in JavaScript. To get cookies properly in JS see that: [Javascript getCookie functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003823/javascript-getcookie-functions/4004010#4004010)
- If you don't want to inject JS code, you can set some attribute like:

  `<div id="comments" data-logged="<?php echo $isLogged; ?>">
  ...
  </div>`

  And get it by jQuery:

  `if ( $("#comments").attr('data-logged') == 1 ) {`
- you can provide logged/notlogged specific functionality for the whole page by generating JS file, like: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yoursite.com/somefile.php">` and generate it in php dynamically, but be aware of caching !

Personally i would go to data-XXX attribute if tou want to personalize single block, and global JS variable if you check logged condition many times in JS.

Comment: Thanks this looks great. Can I ask why you might call the variable {document.mysite.userlogged} instead of just {userlogged}?

Comment: userlogged can be fine, but be aware of javascript scopes and closures, document.... cleanly signs that we think about global variable. Also if you want to set `document.mysite.variable` first you must `document.mysite = {}`