# SetCookiePhp and GetCookie Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, cookies, null

Is it possible to set/get cookies between php and javascript?

I tried two cases:

- setCookie on Javascript, and then getCookie on PHP, it works
- setCookie on PHP, and getCookie on Javascript, then it failed, always return null.

I am wondering if it is supposed to work in this way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003823/javascript-getcookie-functions

Comment: Thanks Dasun, But I don't think that what I want

Comment: Oh I thought you are following W3Schools and Having ann issue

Comment: Could you please provide some sourceCode?

Comment: Hi, Chris. In my PHP page, I use this to setCookie: setcookie($GLOBAL_COOKIE_KEY_CREATED_CV_THEME_ID, $param_themeId, time()+$GLOBAL_COOKIE_EXPIREDAYS, '/');

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue was, my php folder is under a different directory apart from html page.

I went through the php documentation about cookies, and found out that Cookies can be saved for specific page which is depending on the path you specified.

What I did changed right now is specify the path as '/', so the cookie will be available for all pages:

```
setcookie($GLOBAL_COOKIE_KEY_CREATED_CV_THEME_ID, $param_themeId, time()+$GLOBAL_COOKIE_EXPIREDAYS, '/');
```

Ref: http://us.php.net/setcookie

Hope this could help, but if someone found it's wrong, please comment, thanks.