# Pass Variable (cookie) from local html to UILabel - iOS

Tags: html, ios, variables, cookies

I wanted to know how I could go about passing a Variable (cookie) in a local HTML file in my iOS App, and pass what the cookie says onto a UILabel. Here is what the HTML code is. I need to pass this message into a UILabel

```
<script language="javascript">setCookie('Test','You Sir have succeeded. Congratulations.', 300);
 </script>
```

And here is my updated code for iOS app

Header File:

## import

@interface ViewController : UIViewController  {

```
IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
IBOutlet UILabel *mylabel;


}

  @end
```

Main File

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

 @implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DTPContent/cookietest" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *myCookie = [self->webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getCookie('Test')"]; self->mylabel.text = myCookie;

    }

    @end
```

Thank You in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have a javascript function to get the cookies, like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003823/javascript-getcookie-functions/4004010#4004010), you can simply execute the javascript with webview's method `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` , get it's returned string and set it in a UILabel.

It will be something like this:

```
NSString *myCookie = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getCookie('Test')"];
self.mylabel.text = myCookie;
```

Comment: I updated my code that i put in the app, After connecting outlets, The Uilabel is just blank

Comment: Have you pasted the javascript function `getCookie()` inside your HTML? If it's blank, probably the javascript method its not been correctly called. I suggest you to first test it with a javascript console in a desktop web browser. When you succeed in get the cookies with javascript inside the console, just post the same code in the ios method `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`.