# How to include X-CSRF-Token when using Jeditable Ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, csrf, jeditable

I'm using Jeditable and jQuery (obviously) and I need to send X-CSRF-Token in every Ajax request. How can I do it?

Jeditable does not seem to support this issue. (or am I wrong?)

Answer (score 1):

My simple solution is to make JQuery include my X-CSRF-Token in every Ajax request. Just add:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': getCookie('myCsrfToken')
    }
});
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003823/javascript-getcookie-functions) for proper 'getCookie' function.